# Create Different Session for two similar database

Tags: php, database, session, mysqli

I have created demo DB which is replica of original DB.

> Background:

When user successfully login, a session id is created.

> Issue:

When user login with demo account, lets say UserId=1, Session id "1" is generated.

Now if this same user change URL to original URL, he is still logged-in and can access record of "UserID=1" of original account which is not desirable.

Can anyone figure out a solution how to solve this issue?

**EDIT :** can't use different session id name as whole code refers to $_SESSION["id"]

Answer (score 0):

You must be using the same session variable to check access to both the databases.

Define two different session variables like `$_SESSION['login_demo']` and `$_SESSION['login_main']`.

If the demo session is set the user will get access to the demo DB, if the main session is set then give access to the main DB.

Comment: can't use different session id name as whole code refers to $_SESSION["id"]. Have to rewrite entire code if I have to change $_SESSION["id"] to $_SESSION["id_demo"]

Comment: @Entrepreneur then create another column in the user table of both the DB and change its value according to the login status of the user. Based on that value you have to segregate them.